# How to increase concurrent connections of node js/express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have come across `posix` npm package. Was this is used to increase concurrent connections?

Answer (score 1):

yes......Use the posix module to raise the limit on the number of file descriptors your process can use.

var posix = require('posix');
posix.setrlimit('nofile', { soft: 10000 });

Comment: Does the 10000 mean 10000 concurrent connections? If we want to put them to unlimited, what we have to do?

Comment: no idea about the unlimited part.but, generally whenl we call  setrlimit() it identifies a specific resource to be operated upon as well as a resource limit. A resource limit is a pair of values, one specifying the current (soft) limit, the other a maximum (hard) limit.                            var posix = require('posix'); posix.setrlimit('nofile', { soft: 10000, hard: 10000  });